# Webview in android able to run php

Tags: php, android

I am working on a Android Application that has web view where i need to load html, jquery and js and php also. Now i am able to load html jquery css javascript , But my problem is i am unable to load php in web view in offline is there any way to execute php in web view 
Please Help Me Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want to run PHP on your Android.  But in case you do, then you would want http://code.google.com/p/php-for-android/.  Better link: http://phpforandroid.net/

Answer (score 4):

PHP is a server side language. It cannot run inside the browser. It helps you to build the dynamic web pages.

You can call any web page in the webview when you are online. it doesn't matter what is the server side language.

When you are offline, you cannot send request to any server. so no question of executing any page.

Comment: if the webpage is something like "http://example.com/sample.php" which displays some list in webpage. what happens if we access that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easyly with AndroPhp, just search it in Google play and install.

Its like WampServer for Php+Mysql. You should run it than just create your PHP project under www/ folder and call it from Android webview 127.0.0.1:80/yourproject

This way you you have local server on your Android, you shouldnt code in Java for Android all you can code in PHP. Maybe it is not a elegant way to code for Android but works !!