# android webview can see my protected page

Tags: php, android, session, webview

I have a protected page and its codes like;

```
<?php
if (session_id() == "")
 {
 session_start();
 }
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
 {
 header('Location: ./index.php');
  exit;
 }
else
 {
    //something after user entered
 }
?>
```

My android webview can see this page before user enter the system. Why is it like that ? How can I fix it ? Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. What does the page show then? The client should have no session.

Comment: Are you clearing your cache including your cookies before you test? I think you have a lingering active session in your browser.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen result : I can see my protected page content on my android phone. So php page doesn't work for android webview, right?

Comment: Android does not interpret php, you need a webserver for that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750619/webview-in-android-able-to-run-php

Comment: @cryptic how can I clean emulator cache with codes, can you please give an example. Thank you

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sorry What you mean, I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use the

```
webView.clearCache(true);
```

to clear the cache.
There are also other useful things like
clearHistory();
clearFormData();
etc.

And things like:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

More info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Oh and as others have mentioned, PHP is serverside so if you trying to use them locally from the App it wont go well.

Comment: I suspect that the header command is causing problems, when you put die() instead of header does it work ?

Comment: @vodich using die() will kill the script, which is what exit() is doing as well. header() will not cause the problem since all it is doing is setting an HTTP header to redirect, which does not effect the session unless it is setting a cookie which it is not.

Comment: above code doesn't work. Sorry, Where I 'm going to put die() ?

Comment: @cryptic All I wanted is to see if the script even gets to header(). I suspect that webview behaves strangely because of header so I thought to add die()  just for debug purposses

Comment: Put die() instead of header and see if the script dies just to check if session is working in webview

Comment: Can you pu absolute url in header() ? Maybe index page is not located in ./index.php ?

Comment: I solved it . I went to profile page in webview then I saw my account still open. I loged out. Now I can't see protected page.