# PHP code not able to run along with Android App

Tags: php, android

- I have created an app in which there is a login page (login.php).This consists of the form

  - The other script I have created is loginScript.php
  - When I try to run the code, login.php, it does runs in the webview of app but when hit "sign in" button, the action calls the
    loginScript.php but it does not runs instead whole scripts displayed.

    > It is working when I do the same from any browser.

  > Kindly suggest what should I do to run the php script in the app (Internet is active)

Comment: Do both scripts reside on the same server?

Comment: @Julie Pelletier, I didn't get you

Comment: Are `login.php` and `loginScript.php` on the same machine and accessed the same way?

Comment: You want to run the php scripts on your device right? [Look here](https://androidwebdev.wordpress.com/how-to-run-php-code/)

Comment: @PrakashLal show ur php script and how u r implementing it on device side

Comment: @dhiraj,my php script is all working properly.It is working perfectly from any browser. But when i try to implement the same from the .apk file, it is not runing the php script as if there is no server

Comment: @PrakashLal how can you execute php without server?? As it is server side scripting language follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750619/webview-in-android-able-to-run-php

Comment: @PrakashLal, To run Php, u need a server with php installed (Apache etc). Android OS does not have that hence anything written with <?php tag will just be rendered by device web view as plain text. Separate you Server Side logic and put that on a server, use stuffs like ajax or java to call the server side script.

Answer (score -2):

You must be missing < ? php    opening tag.

Comment: no i am not... it is working when i do it from browser

Comment: Are u calling login.php or loginScript.php from android?

Comment: ,yes,from android app

Comment: php scripts run same way either u call from browser or android, android receives the strings u echo... so in loginScipt.php u should have to only echo the json object having value success or other values as u wish, after whole processing.